# What is the meaning of oIMR

Tags: pcr

In reference to genotyping primers, often some are labeling with 'oIMR'. It seems that this often refers to internal positive control primers, but I'm not sure. What does this stand for?

Comment: it stands for oligo Induced Mutant Resource.